# Start SecurityHealthService in winapi in C++?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Is there any way to start Start SecurityHealthService in winapi in C++? I am trying to run:

```
SERVICE_STATUS Status;
SC_HANDLE SCManager = OpenSCManager(NULL, NULL, SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS);
SC_HANDLE SHandle = OpenService(SCManager, _T("SecurityHealthService"), SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS);
```

and I am getting `SHandle == NULL`. The resources on winapi are limited in the internet but maybe I am missing something. For now I'd like to not care about the permission issue here if we do not have rights for run this service.
Thanks!

Comment: `SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS` wrong access for `OpenService` call. you need `SERVICE_START` here

Comment: As I understand that giving me only permission for Starting this service?

Comment: yes, if need more - look for [*Access Rights for a Service*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/service-security-and-access-rights#access-rights-for-a-service)

Comment: From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/nf-winsvc-openscmanagera): *"If the function fails, the return value is NULL. To get extended error information, call [`GetLastError`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-getlasterror)."* When you do, it'll probably return `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`. *"I'd like to not care about the permission issue here"* - That's just another way of saying: *"I want to avoid learning about the solution."*